# Run jest tests in docker-compose with mongodb and redis

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, jestjs

I've an application which uses mongodb and redis.

I want to execute tests on docker-compose, but every time i ran test I get the following error.

Command: `docker-compose -p tests run --rm main npm run test`

Error:

```
 FAIL  test/content/document/content.document.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'request'

      at node_modules/request-promise-native/lib/rp.js:8:12
      at module.exports (node_modules/stealthy-require/lib/index.js:62:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/request-promise-native/lib/rp.js:7:15)
```

I tried to install `request` but no success.

The tests run successfully local without docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: npm run start:dev
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongodb

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:5
    networks:
      - webnet

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=database
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    image: mongo:4.2.6
    restart: always
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

networks:
  webnet:
```

Dockerfile:

```
# https://blog.logrocket.com/containerized-development-nestjs-docker/

FROM node:10.20.1-alpine3.11 As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:10.20.1-alpine3.11 as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT=8080

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "jest-docker",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "build:docker": "docker build -t paperbot .",
    "deploy": "npm run build && gcloud app deploy --quiet",
    "docker": "PORT=8080 docker-compose up --build --rm -V",
    "start": "NODE_PATH=. npm run start:prod",
    "start:dev": "PORT=8080 NODE_PATH=. nest start --watch",
    "start:prod": "NODE_PATH=. node dist/main.js",
    "test": "NODE_PATH=. ts-node ./dck",
    "test:docker": "docker-compose -p tests run --rm main npm run test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/bull": "^0.1.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.11.11",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.4.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.11.11",
    "@nestjs/cqrs": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.11.11",
    "@slack/bolt": "^2.1.1",
    "bull": "^3.14.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "embedly": "^2.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "js-video-url-parser": "^0.4.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.8",
    "node-nlp": "^4.4.0",
    "raw-body": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tsscmp": "^1.0.6",
    "unfluff": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.11.11",
    "@release-it/conventional-changelog": "^1.1.4",
    "@testdeck/jest": "^0.1.0",
    "@types/bull": "^3.13.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.5.18",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.24",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.3",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/tsscmp": "^1.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "dockest": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-json-format": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "release-it": "^13.6.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "supertest": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "coverage",
    "reportFile": "test-reporter.xml",
    "indent": 2
  }
}
```

I tried also with [Dockest](https://github.com/erikengervall/dockest) and got the same error.

Comment: Can you please add your `pacakge.json`?

Comment: Yes, I just did.

Comment: As you can see, `request` module is not part of dependencies as well `devDependencies`, please run `npm install request --production`

Comment: Hey, in fact, it did resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, `request` module is not part of dependencies as well `devDependencies`, please run

```
npm install request --production
```